# How to not specify an optional parameter?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The img function for the canvas context has parameters like this:

img, sx (optional), sy (optional), swidth (optional), sheight (optional), x, y

As you can see, there are optional parameters in between img and x. How would I specify that I don't want to use sx sy swidth or sheight and skip to x?

Comment: `null` usually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `ctx.drawImage` can not skip arguments!!

You can not skip any of the optional arguments for this function.

You must pass 3, 5, or 9 arguments.

If you add values that are not numbers like `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `true`, etc for all but the first argument, the value will be coerced to a number.

If you pass anything but a valid image as the first argument the call will throw an error.

### Examples of what throws and not.

```js
const c = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function test(func, message) {
  try {
    func();
    console.log(message)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(message + e.message)
  }
}

test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0), "drawImage(img,x,y) OK");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0, 10, 10), "drawImage(img, x, y, w, h) OK");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10), "drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh) OK");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, null, 0), "drawImage(c,null,0)  OK null is converted to 0");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, undefined, 0), "drawImage(c,undefined,0) OK undefined is converted to 0");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, 0), "drawImage(c,0) Error:");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0, 10), "drawImage(c,0,0,10) Error:");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0), "drawImage(c,0,0,10,10,0,0) Error:");
test(() => ctx.drawImage(null, 0, 0), "drawImage(null,0,0) Error:");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` method, then it actually allows you to just pass those three arguments:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
```

For more information, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).